# Flex Console - How to use it?

Tags: apache-flex, console, logging

I'm checking "Flex Console" --> [here](http://code.google.com/p/flex-developer-tools/downloads/list) that looks really interesting. 
It seems easy to use and light to integrate. But how? I've been looking around for some info about it but haven't been successful. I found [this](http://log5f.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-localconnectionappender-with-minidebug-applications/) post but I don't understand how it is used...
If anyone have any idea on how to use it or have any recommendation about any other app that would do the same (save clear flex logs with filters and stuff) I'd be really appreciated.

Regards,
BS_C3

Answer (score 0):

Flex Console has moved to a new location: http://code.google.com/p/flex-console/

In a nutshell, you create a MiniDebugTarget in your project and start logging using the Logging API.

```
import mx.logging.*;
import mx.logging.targets.*;

public class MyApp {

    static private logger:ILogger = Log.getLogger("sample.MyApp");

    public function MyApp() {
        super();
        // Add the MinuDebugTarget to channel
        // all log messages to LocalConnection
        // You only need to do this once!
        var target:MiniDebugTarget = new MiniDebugTarget();
        target.filters = ["*"];
        target.includeDate = true;
        target.includeTime = true;
        target.includeCategory = true;
        target.includeLevel = true;
        Log.addTarget(target);
    }

    public function foo(bar:String):void {
        logger.debug("foo({0})", bar);
        try {
            //    do something
            ..
        } catch(e:Error) {
            logger.error("Error: ", e.message);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the Help page at the new site.